# Handle UIPanGesture which started in area where gesture isn't attached but panned into view where gesture is attached

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer

I think the picture will describe the problem:

The yellow view has a pan gesture attached to it.

Touch was initiated in red area

finger was dragged into yellow area - but the pan gesture doesn't get initiated

[image]

The red area does not have a pan gesture attached to it.

The yellow area has a pan gesture attached to it

The green area has a pan gesture attached to it

When the user starts dragging a finger downwards - eventually it will enter into the area (yellow) where the gesture recognizer is attached.

But because the touch wasn't initiated in the yellow area - the pan gesture will never kick off.

What is the solution to this - without making the yellow area larger (even clear is a bad option because I don't want the views to overlap)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case the best option would be to add the pan gesture recogniser to the super view and then in your pan handling method use:

```
CGPoint panLocation = [recogniser locationInView:superView];
```

and then check where it is with something like:

```
if (recogniser.state == UIGestureRecogniserStateMoved) {
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(yellowView.frame, panLocation)) {
        // Do something
    } else if (CGRectContainsPoint(greenView.frame, panLocation)) {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: super view doesn't contain the red area

Comment: Does, one view contain both the yellow and green views, and then another contains that one and the red view?